# How to simplify LDAP authentication in Spring Boot to reduce data loading process time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, batch-processing, restful-authentication

We have a batch process and 4 Spring micro-services called via REST endpoints. Each micro-service has LDAP authentication. While running batch process, LDAP authentication takes 80% of time, which slows down data loading process significantly. Is there any recommendation to simplify authentication? Currently we use LDAP authentication.

Comment: This link will be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16067004/3728901

Answer (score 1):

Caching of LDAP user accounts is an option, but you should be aware of the complexity that a cache would introduce (refresh frequency,size etc).

You can look at creating an Authentication service which does LDAP authentication and if authentication is successful, it could issue an OAUTH2 token.

Rest of the MicroServices can authorise using this token and this will eliminate the need for each MicroService to have a separate LDAP Authentication and will help you to directly overcome the performance issue that you are currently facing